# mathematical expression to unpolarised light

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics

i have already calculated the expression for polarised light but nowhere it is described about unpolarised light.
can anybody tell me the mathematical expression to unpolarised light?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly monochromatic unpolarized light does not exist. Unpolarized light is a sum of light with different polarization directions and a certain bandwidth of frequencies.

At any instant, the E-field has a certain direction. The time length that it oscillates with this direction is the coherence time. The bandwidth must be at least as large as the reciprocal value of the coherence time.

One way to deal with this mathematically is [Mueller calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mueller_calculus).

Answer (score 1):

The electric field of a transverse electromagentic plane wave propagating along the $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ direction is given by:
$$\mathbf{E}=E_x\hat{\mathbf{x}}+E_y\hat{\mathbf{y}}$$
Using this representation of the electric field, we can use Stokes parameters to describe polarisation. There are 4 Stokes parameters: $S_0$, $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$. $S_0$ is basically the Intensity of the light and is defined as follows:
$$S_0=\langle E_x^2+ E_y^2\rangle$$
and is usually normalized. The other 3 parameters are defined as follows:
$$S_1=\langle E_x\rangle ^2-\langle E_y\rangle^2$$
$$S_2=2\langle \text{Re}(E_xE_y^*)\rangle $$
$$S_3=-2\langle\text{Im}(E_xE_y^*)\rangle $$
$S_1$ and $S_2$ describe the orientation of the linear polarisation of the light and $S_3$ describes the ellipticity of the polarisation. Using these paramenters, we can define the degree of polarisation (DOP) as follows:
$$p=\sqrt{\dfrac{S_1^2+S_2^2+S_3^2}{S_0^2}}$$
when $p=0$, you have completely unpolarised light, or that the light is made up of a superposition of randomly oriented polarisations.

Comment: How would you get $p=0$?

Comment: When $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ are all zero. It is a special case and it corresponds to "natural light". Natural light has no preferential polarization and is therefore completely unpolarized light.

Comment: So that is the same case as the "superposition of randomly oriented polarisations". It is not monochromatic. But $S_1=0$ implies $E_x= E_y$?

Comment: Its not monochromatic light, but its is still unpolarized. $S_1=0$ implies that the diference of the time averages of each component is 0.

Comment: Ah, you edited absolute values to expectation values. Still your "or" just means that it is the same thing.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can have monochromatic light with ramdonly oriented polarizations. For instance, in a laboratory, one can use a polarization scrambler to generate a laser beam with 0 degree of polarization, and a laser is practically a monochromatic source of light.

Comment: Ah, "practically". But "monochromatic light with randomly oriented polarizations" you cannot have. Not mathematically, and that is what @tapas asked for.

Comment: He never mentioned anything about monochromatic light...